# How to add additional attributes to the JSON response in my Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, optional-parameters

I am using Rails 5.2 for my application.

Request:

```
http://localhost:3000/reports
```

Response:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Ram",
        details: {
            path: "dev/daily_summary_20190503.csv",
            success_detail: "Report uploaded to S3"
        },
        status: "success"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "John",
        details: {
            path: "dev/daily_summary_20190504.csv",
            error_detail: "Error in uploading report. Refer log for details"
        },
        status: "failed"
    }
]
```

I want to add download_url, message parameters to every records where parameters is not added to schema. Following is my expected output,

Expected output:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Ram",
        details: {
            path: "dev/daily_summary_20190503.csv",
            success_detail: "Report uploaded to S3"
        },
        status: "success",
        download_url: "https://<S3_HOST>/dev/daily_summary_20190503.csv",
        message: "Report uploaded to S3"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "John",
        details: {
            error_detail: "Error in uploading report. Refer log for details"
        },
        status: "failed",
        message: "Error in uploading report. Refer log for details"
    }
]
```

I have tried using attr_accessor, but which doesn't help me to display download_url in all records of index method in controller.

How can I add the paramters for index and show of every records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the JSON that is in the HTTP response you need to find the place where the JSON is generated. Follow the trail from the request URL:

- use `rails routes` on the command line
- in the outbut, find your url **/reports** and read which controller + action it is mapped to
- open the controller file (probably **/app/controllers/reports_controller.rb**) and find the action (probably **index**)
- look at the end of the action

If you find a **render** statement like this:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  # index.html.erb
    format.json  { render :json => @reports }
  end
```

you need to follow the block after **format.json**.  In this example you see
that the data that is displayed is stored in the **@reports** variable.
study the action to find out how the data is created.  The data is
then rendered using the template **/app/views/reports/index.json.jbuilder**.
Read up on [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).

In a more complex application instead of jbuilder [ActiveModelSerializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) might be used.

Comment: Thanks. I can add the extra parameter using https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers.